# vim arrow keys insert mode mapping

Tags: vim, key-mapping

I want to move the cursor without using arrow keys in insert mode too. I've tried the following:

```
:imap <A-h> <Left>
```

but after moving cursor left by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> from insert mode I get back to normal mode, which makes this mapping useless.

Comment: This could answer to your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17334388/2231796 . However, movement on insert mode shall be considered counterproductive - http://csswizardry.com/2014/06/vim-for-people-who-think-things-like-vim-are-weird-and-hard/ . There are more efficient ways to move arround on vim - http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/02/habit-breaking-habit-making/